# Moving website from new.domainname.com to domainname.com (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I tried moving website from new.thegomelgroup.com to thegomelgroup.com. I updated the links in the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). Now it was navigating to old index page. There was no "new" folder so I didn't moved the wordpress files anywhere.

The problem is I accidentally deleted the addon domain and now the new website is not working at all and showing 404 error. I recreated addon domain but still no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com');
```

Add above to your wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow below seteps.**

- Download and move all the files from sub.domain.com to domain.com.
- Then download database file (.sql) from phpmyadmin from old database.
- Open the .sql file in any text editor like notepad if you are on widnows.
- Find your sub.domain.com and replace it with domain.com URL by performing find and replace command.
- Then create new database and import the .sql file to the new database.
- Go to wp-config.php and change the database and username and password.

Now trying hitting the domain it should work.